# Finding a certain residue

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus, laurent-series

I wish to calculate the value of
\begin{equation}
\text{Res}\big((z+\pi/4)^2\tan(z);z=\pi/2\big)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_C (z+\pi/4)^2\tan(z)\text{d}z,
\end{equation}
where $C$ is any counter-clockwise simple closed contour enclosing only $\pi/2$ from the poles of $\text{tan}$.

I've noticed that if the power of $z+\pi/4$ is $1$ instead of $2$ then one can integrate by parts along some, e.g., square contour $C$, and evaluate and sum the corresponding "edge" line integrals. But I imagine this trick fails here because there is no explicit formula for the anti-derivative of $\log(\cos)$ (that I know of!).

Might there be any other trick to achieve this? How difficult ought it be to calculate, e.g., the Laurent series of the integrand? Any ideas are most welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$R=\operatorname{Res}\left((z+\pi/4)^2 \tan(z); z=\pi/2\right) = -\operatorname{Res}\left((z+3\pi/4)^2 \cot(z); z=0\right)$$
and since in a neighbourhood of the origin:
$$ \cot z = \frac{1}{z}-\frac{z}{3}-\frac{z^3}{45}+o(z^4),$$
$$ (z+3\pi/4)^2 = \frac{9\pi^2}{16}+\frac{3\pi}{2}z + z^2 $$
we just have:
$$ R = \color{red}{-\frac{9\pi^2}{16}}.$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer, very cunning. If I may offer a little advice, though, it may be prudent to ask first whether the OP wants a complete answer or simply some hints to be nudged in a productive direction. Anyway, thanks again!